# Insertion/Removal animation in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui

I'm trying to achieve this animation for insertion of an element in a `VStack`, all elements move down to create space for the new one and then the new one is inserted from right to left.
The code bellow does the insertion as I described, but how to make it work for removal as well, the animation should be similar, the element is completely removed (to the right), then the other elements move up)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var show = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            show ? Rectangle().frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
                .animation(Animation.easeIn(duration: 0.5).delay(1))
                .transition(.move(edge: .trailing)): nil
            
            Rectangle().frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
            Rectangle().frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
            Rectangle().frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
            Rectangle().frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
            
            Button("Add") {
                show.toggle()
            }
            Spacer()
            
        }.animation(Animation.easeIn(duration: 0.5))
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have that many `Rectangle()`s, you should use a `ForEach`. This will make adding and removing them much easier, because you can just `append` and `removeLast` to change how many are showing.

Here's what I did:

1. Make a new struct that represents a `Rectangle`
2. The `added` property will control whether the `Rectangle` is shown or not
3. Define an array of `RectangleInfo` that will be shown to the user
4. Use `ForEach` to loop over the `rectangles`
5. Instead of a `transition`, you can use `offset` to have more control over the animation.

Once the UI is set up, it's time for the animations:

6. First append a rectangle, to make space for it
7. Once it's appended, set `added` to true so it slides in
8. Set `added` to false to slide it out
9. Once it slid out, remove it from the array and also remove the space.

```
struct RectangleInfo: Identifiable { /// 1.
    let id = UUID()
    var added = true /// 2.
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var rectangles = [ /// 3.
        RectangleInfo(),
        RectangleInfo(),
        RectangleInfo()
    ]
    
    let animationDuration = 0.5
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            ForEach(rectangles) { rectangle in /// 4.
                Rectangle().frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
                    .offset(x: rectangle.added ? 0 : 200, y: 0) /// 5.
            }
            
            Button("Add") {
                rectangles.append(RectangleInfo(added: false)) /// 6.
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + animationDuration) {
                    rectangles[rectangles.count - 1].added = true /// 7.
                }
            }
            Button("Remove") {
                rectangles[rectangles.count - 1].added = false /// 8.
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + animationDuration) {
                    rectangles.removeLast() /// 9.
                }
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
        }.animation(Animation.easeIn(duration: animationDuration))
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Rectangles stacked vertical with Add and Remove buttons at bottom. Press Add to first make space, then slide the rectangle in. Press Remove to first remove the rectangle, then remove the space.]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly your final outcome should be and my proposed solution is not really "generic", but it should at least give you a starting point.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var show = false
    @State var showPlaceholder = false
    
    // The total animation duration will be twice as long as this value
    private var animationDuration: TimeInterval = 0.5
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            ZStack {
                if showPlaceholder {
                    Color.white.opacity(0.0)
                        .zIndex(1)
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                }
                if show {
                    Rectangle()
                        .zIndex(2)
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
                        .animation(Animation.easeIn(duration: animationDuration))
                    .transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
                }
            }
            
            Rectangle().frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
            Rectangle().frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
            Rectangle().frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
            Rectangle().frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
            
            Button("Add") {
                if show {
                    showPlaceholder(for: animationDuration)
                    show = false
                }
                else {
                    showPlaceholder(for: animationDuration) {
                        show = true
                    }
                }
            }
            Spacer()
            
        }.animation(Animation.easeIn(duration: animationDuration))
    }
    
    private func showPlaceholder(for timeInterval: TimeInterval, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        showPlaceholder = true
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: timeInterval, repeats: false) { (_) in
            showPlaceholder = false
            completion?()
        }
    }
}
```